# Using XSD to validate one element, or other element, or both

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm using an XSD file and C# .NET to validation XML. I need to validate the `<Message>` element has either:

> `<Edit>`
> OR
> `<Delete>`
> OR
> `<Edit> <Delete>` (IE both elements)

Can this be done in XSD?

Comment: Can you upload a minimal reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this XSD,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Message">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="Edit"/>
          <xs:element name="Delete" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Delete"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

will allow `<Edit/>` or `<Delete/>` or `<Edit/><Delete/>`, as requested.